# Two different instances give the same result (Python)

Tags: python

I have no clue why by creating two different instances I get the same result? What is wrong with my logic? (updated to working)

Basically, this class should create a list of dates in the according year

The code itself:

```
class Date:

    def __init__(self, year):
        self.year = year

    def dateStr(self, date):
        if date < 10:
            date = '0' + str(date)
        else:
            date = str(date)
        return date

    def daysInMonth(self, month):
        if month == 4 or month == 6 or month == 9 or month == 11:
            endDate = 30
        if month == 1 or month == 3 or month ==5 or month == 7 or month ==8 or month == 10 or month == 12:
            endDate = 31
        if self.year%4 == 0 and month == 2:
            endDate = 29
        if self.year%4 != 0 and month == 2:
            endDate = 28
        return endDate

    def makeDate(self):
        self.date = []
        month = 1
        while month <= 12:
            day = 1
            while day <= self.daysInMonth(month):
                    self.date.append(str(self.dateStr(day)) + u'.' + str(self.dateStr(month)) + u'.' + str(self.year))
                day += 1
            month += 1
        return self.date

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.makeDate())

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.makeDate())

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.makeDate()[key]

date1 = Date(2012)
date2 = Date(2013)
print date1[364]
print date2[364]
```

Thanks for support,
Alex

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: `len(date) < 366)` does not look right. You might have to use the `global date` in `makeDate()`

Comment: Two lists of dates for the year 2012, whereas I expect to get one for 2012 and another for 2013

Comment: karthikr, ok, but when I specify it as self.date everywhere in the code, it throws sth like 'str don't have an option "append"'. Basically, I change "date" to "self.date" everything and put "self.date = []" in the __init__ def in the code. Is it correct to do so?

Comment: @user2619492 When I run your code, the results are not lists, but strings. Furthermore, you should not use a global variable if you're already using classes. In your constructor, `self.date = []`, and then refer to it as `self.date` so that the instances of your class don't conflict.

Comment: In addition to the many answers accurately noting that you're modifying a global variable without intending to do so...why not just use the built in `datetime` library? It wouldn't be hard to build a list of all dates in a given year using it, and for bonus points it handles leap years correctly (unlike this code).

Comment: Thanks everybody, I understood this and corrected it by replacing "date" to "self.date" everywhere and plugging "self.date = []" into my makeDate function. Question is solved to me!

Comment: @Peter DeGlopper: thanks for useful note! I am just trying to catch the logic of language and writing some basic scripts that I need to use.

Comment: @Alekz112: If you're putting `self.date = []` into `makeDate`, and not referencing it anywhere else, you don't need it to be an attribute; just make it a local variable. (The _second_ option from my answer.)

Comment: @abarnert: yes, I see that

Answer (score 4):

Your `makeDate` method modifies a global `date`. When you call it the first time, it adds all 366 days of 2012 to the empty list, then gives you the 364th. When you call it the second time, on the second instance, it adds all 365 days of 2013 to the existing list of 366 days, then gives you the 364th, which is the same as before.

This is exactly why you don't want to use globals. Just put a `self.date = []` in the `__init__` method, and use `self.date` instead of `date`, and each instance will have its own list.

Or you can just make it a local variable instead of a global, so `makeDate` just creates and returns a new list each time it's called.

Comment: Shoot, now I see the logic. Great thanks! But how to change it properly? I mean, how to put self.date in the __init__ function correctly?

Comment: @user2619492: I explained that in the second paragraph: "Just put a `self.date = []` in the `__init__` method." What part of that do you not understand?

Comment: it did not work though

Comment: @Alekz112: "It did not work" is not useful information for anyone who wants to help you debug your code. You have to show us exactly what you did, and in what way it didn't work. Did you get an exception? If so, what's the traceback? Did you get incorrect results? If so, what were the expected and actual results?

Comment: Yes, just like I have said above, if I put it into constructor it throws me the following error: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'". So, when I put "self.data = []" python refers to it as to string but not list. Why is it then?

Comment: @Alekz112, because you've put something else? Update the question with your changes.

Comment: btw, for example, I created two instances (lists), for 2012 and 2013 years, how then to append 2013 to 2012 to create a single list? is there any function for this?

Comment: @Alekz112: You can append one list to another non-destructively with `list1 + list2`, or destructively with `list1.append(list2)` (or `list1 += list2` if you prefer). So if you've created instances that each have such a list in their `date` member, you can use `date1.date + date2.date` to get the two lists appended together.

Comment: @Alekz112, That looks fine, but I think making it an instance variable is still wrong. You should make it local as I showed in my answer. makeDate clearly assumes that date is an empty list which it won't be after the first time you call it.

Comment: @gnibbler: I updated once again to what works for me, check whether it is consistent to what you mean

Comment: @Alekz112: From your comment about appending the two lists together to create a single list, I think you _do_ want to be able to use this list outside of the `makeDate` function, in which case gnibbler's suggestion and mine of using a local variable doesn't work. But you do need to do _something_ differently so you only create the list once instead of repeatedly appending to it. I'd suggest calling `makeDate` in the constructor instead of in each function, or adding a check (`if self.date: return`) to make sure it only builds the list once.

Answer (score 1):

The global `date` is shared by all instances of `Date`, so when you return `date` from `Date.makeDate`, you are returning a reference to that list. `date2[364]` is returning the same element that `date1[364]` did. After calling `Date.__getitem(date2, 364)`, you should notice that `date` has somewhere over 700 items in the list. While `date1[364]` and `date[364]` would be the same, `date2[364]` is really something like `date[728]`. You need to either reset the value of `date` each time you call `makeDate`, or (better yet), ditch the global variable and use a local list inside `makeDate`, initialized to `[]` each time.

Answer (score 0):

You're appending to the global `date` variable. Since it's already modified by the first call, the second is doing nothing and just returning it.

What is `date` supposed to be? I guess probably you mean it to be a local variable

```
def makeDate(self):
    date = []           # brand new empty list
    month = 1
    while month <= 12:
        day = 1
        while day <= self.daysInMonth(month):
            if (self.year%4 == 0 and len(date) < 366) or (self.year%4 != 0 and len(date) < 365):
                date.append(str(self.dateStr(day)) + u'.' + str(self.dateStr(month)) + u'.' + str(self.year))
            day += 1
        month += 1
    return date
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `date` is bound to a list you create outside the class `Date`.

Then, in the various class functions, you manipulate the variable `date`, which refers to the outside-entity list.  This adds various values to the list (which, again, is not associated with any particular class instance) and then returns the list.

It's like doing:

```
x = 3
def f(incr):
    global x
    x += incr
    return x
```

and then wondering why, after incr(1) returns 4, a second incr(1) returns 5.  It's because you're modifying a "global variable".

It's not completely clear to me how you *want* this all to work, but the obvious first step is to get rid of the "global variable" version of `date`, and add a local or instance variable version where needed.